# Realm how to make a query for items that have the size of an array bigger than 0?

Tags: database, list, realm, realm-list

I checked the documentation, and I know how to access objects from within objects, like:

```
RealmResults<User> r1 = realm.where(User.class)
                         .equalTo("dogs.name", "Fluffy")
                         .equalTo("dogs.color", "Brown")
                         .findAll();
```

But if I have in my User.class a realmlist: dogs, how can I check if it has items?

```
RealmResults<User> r1 = realm.where(User.class)
                         .equalTo("dogs.size", 0)
                         .findAll();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `RealmQuery.isEmpty()` like:

```
RealmResults<User> r1 = realm.where(User.class)
                     .isEmpty("dogs")
                     .findAll();
```

See doc [here](https://realm.io/docs/java/0.87.5/api/io/realm/RealmQuery.html#isEmpty-java.lang.String-).